# How to declare the intersection type of variable amount of argument types

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have a function `merge` that accepts a variable amount of object as arguments and creates a new object with a type which is the intersection of the argument types, kind of `Object.assign()`, so `merge({ a: 1 }, { b: 2 })` will return an object with type `{ a: number, b: number}`.

Imagine an implementation like this:

```js
function merge(...objects) {
  // Something like
  return Object.assign({}, ...objects)
}
```

I'm looking for a way to declare its type that allows me to keep the type information in the returned object.

I can only imagine overloading the definition like this:

```js
function merge<A>(a: A): A;
function merge<A, B>(a: A, b: B): A & B;
function merge<A, B, C>(a: A, b: B, c: C): A & B & C;
// etc.
```

which is not convenient given this function is expected to be called with more than five arguments.

Thanks!

Comment: Your title says "union or interception".  Obviously you mean "intersection" (unless this is about American football) but I don't see how "union" is involved.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wR5nYW) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please explain the use cases that don't work here

Comment: @jcalz it works perfectly for my needs. I've added the "union" in the title because I was curious about how to resolve a union also and I supposed the solution would be similar in both cases. I've removed it to leave the question more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single type parameter `T` corresponding to the [tuple type of the rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to `merge()`.  Then you need to come up with a way to take a tuple type and calculate the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of all its element types.  Let's call that type function `IntersectArrayElements<T>`.  So `merge()` will look like:

```
function merge<T extends any[]>(
  ...objects: T
): IntersectArrayElements<T> {
  return Object.assign({}, ...objects)
}
```

Now we just have to implement `IntesectArrayElements<T>`.  There are several ways to do this:

---

A relatively straightforward implementation would be to write a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) that uses [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types):

```
type IntersectArrayElements<T extends any[]> =
  T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? F & IntersectArrayElements<R> : unknown;
```

It splits the tuple `T` into its first element `F` and the rest of the tuple `R`, and then the result is `F` intersected with `IntersectArrayElements<R>`, and if the `T` is already empty (or an array and not a tuple) then it produces [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) which gets absorbed into all intersections.

---

If you have very long tuples, the above implementation could hit recursion limits (something like 25 or 50 or maybe 100 elements).  An improvement over the above for TypeScript 4.5+ would be to rewrite this as a [tail-recursive type function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) which TypeScript can handle more efficiently on tuples up to 1000 elements:

```
type IntersectArrayElements<T extends any[], A = unknown> =
  T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? IntersectArrayElements<R, A & F> : A;
```

This is essentially the same algorithm, except it collects the result in an accumulator type parameter `A`.

---

The recursive implementations are probably the easiest to understand, but recursion can be a bit expensive, especially if used with other type functions which may themselves be recursive.  If you can implement something without recursion then it's probably best to do so.  And there is a way to write `IntersectArrayElements<T>` without recursion, albeit in a less obvious manner:

```
type IntersectArrayElements<T extends any[]> = {
  [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void
}[number] extends (x: infer I) => void ? I : never;
```

This works by first [mapping the tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) into a new form where each element becomes the parameter type to a function.  So `[{a: string}, {b: number}]` becomes `[(x: {a: string})=>void, (x: {b: number})=>void]`.  Then we [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `number` to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of these functions... so now we'd have `((x: {a: string})=>void)|((x: {b: number})=>void)`.  And from this we use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to infer a single parameter type for that union of functions.  Because function types are [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types) in their parameter types, the compiler infers an *intersection* instead of a union... so now we have `{a: string} & {b: number}`.  Simple, right?

---

For any of those three implementations, the following behavior will be observed with `merge()`:

```
const a = { a: "hello" };
const b = { b: 123 };
const c = { c: true };

const mA = merge(a); // {a: string}
const mAB = merge(a, b); // {a: string} & {b: number}
const mABC = merge(a, b, c); // {a: string} & {b: number} & {c: boolean}
const mAandBorC = 
  merge(a, Math.random() < 0.5 ? b : c) // {a: string} & ({b: number} | {c: boolean})
```

That looks like what you want, hooray!

---

A minor caveat: this will work well when you call `merge()` with a set of arguments whose order and types are known to the compiler.  If the compiler cannot figure out the exact number and order of the arguments, then you might get less desirable output types:

```
const forgotOrder = [a, b];
const mOops = merge(...forgotOrder);
```

Here, the type inferred for `forgotOrder` is the unordered array type `Array<{a: string} | {b: number}>`.  By the type we call `merge()`, the compiler has no idea how many elements are in `forgotOrder` or whether or not both `{a: string}` and `{b: number}` elements are present.  And so the type of `mOops` is `IntersectArrayElements<Array<{a: string} | {b: number}>>`, which is either `{a: string} | {b: number}` itself or possibly `unknown` depending which implementation you use above.  It's not clear what type *should* come out of such a weird call, so that's why I'd say this is minor.  It's possible to try to harden `merge()` against such situations, but it's probably out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlAlmGAbCAlC8ArgE5RoBuyA3gLABQSSALgJ4zICSwTEpBTAQWLEQLAKI5I3KAB4AKkggAPHsAAmUJCGAsA2gF0AfEgC89RowXLVGpLrTAAZryQAxADRIAdD4fPiSLj6SAD8bkgAZEhcPHzwgsKiEhBSTLK4xgBcSITAANbAAPYA7sAA3PTmSI658WiFwEiQxADmEPKKKhDqmtp6RgAUPl6FAEYAVvxQ2XIAlNkxvFD8QiLikt1p8sa0DBbEEEwkjQDyE-xeIFBkLcADVAC+nsNjk-FQs1UPlXvwDVBMLSmJBULTZABEAAsIFgsIVwUgHhVfv9AaNgaDRtkAIwAJgAzIjkYw-sAAUh4BiKdkmMRCMgkT8SaimgJgc02gMQLMykgAPR8kEgbIA4gOFrfFFkwFgAQAIXZvE5IE8ox5-MFVGFSFF4oekRBWKQwEIYFGvElzOlrLlAGFFa0IFzVZ54OqBUKRbS9QaqEaTWaLb74NlRoVCjhtJaKSzZdo1HLCsR7SYmkqnSqkABZEBMSFeETqQpgAazJAyJAABi8AFZQkh0dk3RrPTrvcAJQb7v7TebiPqAD4gkMN8OR4APT50SX0UCQWAIZD4IikCjUKqsdjRbhLFaJdYpTayKxdHpaHQGTxs1O5AolYDGMx7SydGyaexOFweby+T8BIL1oscQJGsySpOkV4Gq4WRIAIyJVDUwB1A0aaOh01jdLYfQGIYQw+K8UwzPM26xMs8SrEkGzSNsIJVIwBxHMQpznPElzXGgtz3E8P4jCxaRTowM5SuSIBUtqUIwnCCKMsJaJUkaeKEjJVrkpSqagiOtL0kSTIxtasoOsq7qatquodtGpLkrKCqphyGaqsZrZmZ2UR+tkAZ9hZsbyimqHKi6FKOVqXpiuZvo9oG-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-fGSeQrmzCjZo2eJyABza+SjhJi0hRMCcxBqC4qa6Pr+jDzKJyFDAmi2emeFeKPrQT1PM-EFTfIAFR6VZK9r9kuwWBYgfisSiJIA1S2MJrvAP-qx98rHgrZzGecF2qGPCezBoRICTAfYYoC0CaBgcAAA5ICY+xRiANBaKfUYhBASDXgZoIogIrhIHHoUduacu6Ai2oQeBv02jYJ2pQpALdli-QGgceICcfgPCAA)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!